# Error on production with custom module

Tags: magento2, module, error, template, custom

on production server I get `main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'my.phtml' in module: MyVendor_myModule`, on dev machine everything works fine. How do I debug this?

under `app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/View/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml`

```
<body>

    <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
        <block class="MyVendor\MyModule\Block\Custom" name="product.share" template="MyVendor_MyModule::custom.phtml" after="-" />
    </referenceContainer>

</body>
```

Comment: show your declaration of my.phtml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that the following file exists:

```
app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/view/<area>/templates/my.phtml
```

Where `<area>` must be replace by either `adminhtml` or `frontend` depending on which area you get the error.

Comment: in my case area is there `frontend/layout frontend/templates` but as I said the problem is on remote server

Comment: can be a problem if View directory name start with uppercase?

Comment: yes its affect the file

Comment: @deroccha yes please change `View` folder to `view`

Comment: @deroccha also ensure the `MyVendor` and `MyModule` are the same case everywhere (consistent with your folder names)

Comment: so yes that was the issue uppercase on view folder

Answer (score 1):

You have to check your uppercase and small letter when working with serverside.

```
MyVendor_myModule is not same with `MyVendor_MyModule`.
```

So you have to check your letter.

May be this  cause problems for you.